# homogeneous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying about system of linear systems and had come across homogeneous systems .
What I wanted to ask was , given a homogeneous system of **n** variables , like this having **4** variables : 
$$a_1x + a_2y + a_3z + a_4w = 0$$
$$a_2x + a_3y + a_4z + a_1w = 0$$
$$a_3x + a_4y + a_1z + a_2w = 0$$
$$a_4x + a_1y + a_2z + a_3w = 0$$
Here , as we know that this system has **zero solution** and we can see that the coefficients are rotating in each of the linear equation .

So , is there any general form for solution of this system other than the zero solution ?

Also , what if we are given the non-zero solution then can we find the values of $$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4) $$

Comment: There is no general form, in a sense that the system must be solved, meaning there are different outcomes to the solution space.  IF they (the rows) are all linearly independent, then the solution is just the 0 vector.  If there is one linearly dependent row, the null space is a line, 2 linearly dependent row gives a planar subspace, etc.

Comment: Can we not somehow use the property that the coefficients are rotating ?

Comment: they are linearly independent.  No other solution

Comment: So you mean to say it will only have zero solution ?

Comment: Yes, now what do you mean by the inverse?  The inverse of the coefficient matrix?  If a matrix is invertible, then the system only has the 0 vector as solution.  If your solution vector is nonzero, your null space (solution to the homogeneous system) depends on the rows (or columns) and their linear dependence.

Comment: Hmm , regarding your comment that it will only have zero solution.
what if $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 1$ , then wont it have infinite solutions ?

Comment: If all $a_k$ are different, the zero vector is the solution as long as the rows are linearly independent.  Again, if the rows are linearly dependent (after row reduction / elimination) you get a row of zeros, then the solution space (null space) varies with the number of rows of zeros you get.  To get a generalized solution when you can let the $a_k$'s be anything is impossible because there are an infinite amount of possibilities leading to an infinite number of solutions.  In the case of the $a_k$'s are equal, your solution space is three dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General sollution to $AX=0$ is the kernel $Ker(A)$.

To say $AX=0$ only have zero solution (trivial kernel $Ker(A)=\left\{ 0 \right\}$) is equivalent to verify the [row reduced echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of matrix A:

$$rref(A)=I$$

In your case:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}a1&a2&a3&a4\\a2&a3&a4&a1\\a3&a4&a1&a2\\a4&a1&a2&a3\end{pmatrix}$$

Just need to verify:

$$rref(A) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

For second question, treat $a_i$ as unknowns:
$$xa_1 + ya_2 + za_3 + wa_4 = 0$$

$$wa_1 + xa_2 + ya_3 + za_4 = 0$$

$$za_1 + wa_2 + xa_3 + wa_4 = 0$$

$$ya_1 + za_2 + wa_3 + xa_4 = 0$$

Then it is another linear system you can solve.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , and could please help on the second part 
which is if we are given a solution , can we deduce all $a_i$ .